# How to prove $1 + 3 + 3^2 + ... + 3^{n-1} = (3^n - 1)/2$ by mathematical induction?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, induction

> $1 + 3 + 3^2 + ... + 3^{n-1} = \dfrac{3^n - 1}2$

I am stuck at

$\dfrac{3^k - 1}2 + 3^k$

and I'm not sure if I am right or not.

Comment: use that $3-1=2$, and that $3^n-1^n=(3-1)(3^{n-1}+\cdots+1)$

Comment: $\frac{3^k-1}{2}+3^k=\frac{3^{k+1}-1}{2}$.

Comment: with added detail, $\frac{3^k - 1}2 + 3^k=\frac{3^k - 1+2\cdot 3^k}2=\frac{3\cdot3^k - 1}2=\frac{3^{k+1} - 1}2$

Answer (score 4):

**Problem.** $\quad$Prove by induction the  following formula: $\quad 1+3+3^2+\dots+3^{n−1} = \dfrac{1}{2}\big(3^n−1\big)\,$.

**Solution.** $\quad$Proof by induction is given in three following steps:

1. *Base:* assume $\,n=2,\,$ then $\;1+3 = 4 = \dfrac{1}{2}\big(3^2−1\big), \,$ so the formula is correct.
2. *Hypothesis:* assume formula holds for some positive integer $\,n.\,$
3. *Induction:* show that formula holds for $\,n+1,\;$ i.e. $\; 1+3+\dots+3^{n−1} + \color{#df0000}{3^n}= \dfrac{1}{2}\big(3^{n+1}−1\big)\,$

   - by induction hypothesis we have $\quad 1+3+3^2+\dots+3^{n−1} = \dfrac{1}{2}\big(3^n−1\big)\,$
   - let us add $\,3^n\,$ to the formula above in order to complete the induction step:
     \begin{align}
     \Big(1+3+3^2+\dots+3^{n−1}\Big) + \color{#df0000}{3^n} & = \dfrac{1}{2}\big(3^{n}−1\big) + \color{#df0000}{3^n} \\ & =
     \dfrac{1}{2}\big(3^{n}−1+2\cdot \color{#cc0000}{3^n}\big)  \\ & =
     \dfrac{1}{2}\big(3\cdot \color{#df0000}{3^n} -1\big)  \\ & =
     \dfrac{1}{2}\big(\color{#df0000}{3^{n+1}} -1\big).
     \end{align}

   Thus we established that 
   $$
   \bbox[4pt, border:solid 2pt #FC0000]{\;1+3+3^2+\dots+3^{n−1} + 3^{n} = \dfrac{1}{2}\big(3^{n+1}−1\big)}
   $$

*Q.E.D.*

Comment: Note that the base case could be $1$.

Answer (score 1):

For $n=1$ is true because $1=(3^1-1)/2=2/2=1$.
Suppose that is true for $n\leq k$.
$1+...+3^{k-1}+3^k=_{HI} \frac{3^k-1}{2}+3^k=\frac{3}{2}3^k-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{3^{k+1}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{3^{k+1}-1}{2}$. And then is true for all $n$

Answer (score 0):

**First, show that this is true for $n=1$:**

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{1-1}3^k=\frac12(3^1-1)$

**Second, assume that this is true for $n$:**

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}3^k=\frac12(3^n-1)$

**Third, prove that this is true for $n+1$:**

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}3^k=$

$\color\red{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}3^k}+3^n=$

$\color\red{\frac12(3^n-1)}+3^n=$

$\frac12(3^n-1+2\cdot3^n)=$

$\frac12(3\cdot3^n-1)=$

$\frac12(3^{n+1}-1)=$

---

Please note that the assumption is used only in the part marked red.

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{3^k - 1}2 + 3^k=\dfrac32 3^k - \dfrac12=\dfrac12 3^{k+1} - \dfrac12=\dfrac12(3^{k+1} - 1)$

Answer (score 0):

Assume
$$S=1+3+3^2+3^3+...+3^{n-1}$$
in this case
$$ 3\cdot S=3\cdot1+3\cdot3+3\cdot3^2+...+3\cdot3^{n-2}+3\cdot3^{n-1}$$
$$ 3\cdot S=3+3^2+3^3+...+3^{n-1}+3^{n}$$
Now subtracting $S$ from $3\cdot S$ we have:
$$3\cdot S-S=-1+3-3+3^2-3^2+3^3-3^3+...+3^{n-1}-3^{n-1}+3^n$$
it is easy to see that the result will be
$$2\cdot S=3^n-1$$
so
$$S=\frac{3^n-1}{2}$$
Replacing $S$ with the original sum we have:
$$1+3+3^2+3^3+...+3^{n-1}=\frac{3^n-1}{2}$$
Q.E.D